# Hiding single series label in legend on apex charts

Tags: reactjs, heatmap, apexcharts

I'm using heatmap chart (https://apexcharts.com/docs/chart-types/heatmap-chart/) and i would like to hide a single item in legend: the series 1 label called "label1".

[image]

The results would be something like:

[image]

So, i just want to **hide a single item in legend** and not the entire series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way would be to use pure js to hide first legend item after chart renders, like this

```
document.querySelectorAll("#chart .apexcharts-legend-series")[0].style.display = "none";
```

Second solution to hide first series using options

```
legend: {
  formatter: (seriesName, opts)=>{
    if(opts.seriesIndex==0) return '' // hides first label
    return seriesName;
  },
  markers: {
    width: [0,12,12,12], // hides first marker
  }
}
```